# Read json file from POST in java

Tags: java, json

How can I unmarhsaller json file like this?

```
{
    "packageId": "11",
    "jsScript": "var divideFn = function(a,b) { return a/b} ",
    "functionName": "divideFn",
    "tests": [
        {
            "testName": "test1",
            "expectedResult": "2.0",
            "params": [
                2,
                1
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a class that works well with packageId, jsScrript, functionName, but not with the tests

```
public class Data {
    private final int packageId;
    private final String jsScript;
    private final String functionName;
    private final List<Tests> tests;

    @JsonCreator
    public Data(@JsonProperty("packageId") String packageId,
               @JsonProperty("jsScript") String jsScript,
               @JsonProperty("functionName") String functionName,
               @JsonProperty("tests") List<Tests> tests) {
        this.packageId = Integer.parseInt(packageId);
        this.jsScript= jsScript;
        this.functionName = functionName;
        this.tests = tests;
    }
    }

    public class Tests{
    public final String testName;
    public final int expectedResult;

    @JsonCreator
    public Tests(@JsonProperty("testName") String testName,
                 @JsonProperty("expectedResult") String expectedResult){
        this.testName= testName;
        this.expectedResult = Integer.parseInt(expectedResult);
    }
}
```

What should I change in classes to make it work well?
I also tried to read tests like String, but it didn't help

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @VikramV When I am trying to make a POST request I get Cannot unmarshal JSON as Data

Comment: Please post the error. If I had to guess, it would be because there's no @JsonProperty for params.

Comment: The code that triggers the unmarshalling would also be helpful. Please add it to the question.

Comment: I think your Test class is missing params attribute. Either add the field or add @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) at Tests class level.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have encountered some problems for deserializing the JSON array `tests` to objects. There are several methods to solve this.

**Method 1**
Add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on your class `Tests` to prevent your code from the exception of *Unrecognized field "params"*.

**Method 2**
Deserialize JSON array `tests` to `List<JsonNode>` if it is not important and you won't further parse it in the future.

**Method 3**
Use follwing class for mapping JSON array `tests` to `List<Test>`.

```
class Test {
    private String testName;
    private Float expectedResult;
    private List<Integer> params;

    //general getters ans setters
}
```

---

BTW, I don't think you need to use `@JsonCreator` for deserialization.